# PHP failing to show error messages

Tags: php

I wrote some code as a start for a username and password registration page but i cant get the first bit to work. The page with the forms corresponding to the variables at the top work fine but when redirected to this page it just gives a blank white page.

I seem to get this error every time i write some code that is not just basic echo or something like that... Can someone tell me what is wrong with the code and is there any good php editor where you can see error messages or somethilng like that?

This is not the first time i get the same blank page error and i would love to know what i'm doing wrong.

```
<?php
$user = $_POST["username"];
$pass = $_POST["password"];
$conf_pass = $_POST["conf_password"];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "webuser1", "12345");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if($pass != $conf_pass) {
  echo ("passwords don't match, <a href="./reg_form.php">return</a>");
}



mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: [`error_reporting`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) can be your friend.

Comment: @ghbarratt giving a link to the manual is nice when you suggest a function. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: "*Php white page*". Not a suitable question title!

Comment: Perhaps a better title would be "PHP failing to show error messages" or something along those lines

Comment: In your above code, if the mysql connection is successful and the passwords do match, I would expect a white page. Because if those conditions are satisfied, you are not outputting anything {Edit, unless the above code fragment is only a part of the page]

Comment: @Bazzz error_reporting can be set in several ways. I personally recommend avoiding the function in favor of setting it in an .htaccess [php_value directive](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php).

Comment: @ghbarratt, I totally agree! But I think that suggesting a possible way is better help than just a mentioning. You can't disagree that your comment WITH the link is better than WITHOUT the link, regardless of which `error_reporting` you point the link to. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A blank white page often indicates a 500 Internet Server Error, which usually means you have a syntax or other error in your code.

In your case the error is in the quotes, try changing to:

```
 echo ("passwords don't match, <a href='./reg_form.php'>return</a>");
```

I suggest turning on error reporting in your code, or you can check your error log, this will tell you what the problem is and the line number.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Also, if using Firebug, you can see the 500 Internal Server Error on the Net tab.

Comment: it seems the error was in the quotes, i feel a little stupid now. thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can set the errors to show using:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ("passwords don't match, <a href="./reg_form.php">return</a>");
```

creates the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in ...

Try changing that line to:

```
echo 'passwords don\'t match, <a href="/reg_form.php">return</a>';
```

[`error_reporting`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) could have revealed this to you (as I suggested in the first comment).

Answer (score 0):

There are errors occurring on your code. To see what error is being generated. Use this command on the top of your page.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get an editor with syntax highlighting and errors like this will stand out. Some like Zend Studio also check for syntax errors.